# In Rails, my model association with a view is causing a new SELECT statement for every row

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have an issue with bringing a view into my app, which calculates a running balance for a transactions table using SQL.  I have the following models:

**account.rb**

```
class Account < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :transactions, dependent: :destroy

    validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50, minimum: 2 }
    validates :starting_balance, presence: true
    #validates_associated :transactions

    after_create :create_initial_transaction

    def create_initial_transaction
        self.update_attributes(current_balance: 0.00)
        Transaction.create(trx_type: 'credit', trx_date: DateTime.now, account_id: self.id, description: "Starting Balance", amount: self.starting_balance)
        #self.update_attributes(current_balance: @initbalance)
    end

end
```

**transaction.rb**

```
class Transaction < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :account
    has_one :transaction_balance

    delegate :running_balance, to: :transaction_balance

    attr_accessor :trx_type

    #default_scope { order('trx_date, id DESC') }
    validates_presence_of :trx_type, :message => "Please select debit or credit"
    validates :trx_date, presence: true
    validates :description, presence: true, length: { maximum: 150 }
    validates :amount, presence: true, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 0 }
    validates :memo, length: { maximum: 500 }

    before_save :convert_amount
    after_create :update_account_balance_new
    after_update :update_account_balance_edit
    after_destroy :update_account_balance_destroy

    scope :with_balance, -> { joins(:transaction_balance) }
    scope :desc, -> { order('trx_date, id DESC') }

    # Determine the transaction_type for existing records based on amount
    def transaction_type
        if !new_record?
            if self.amount >= 0
                return ['Credit', 'credit']
            else
                return ['Debit', 'debit']
            end
        else
            return ['Debit', 'debit']
        end
    end

private

    def convert_amount
        if self.trx_type == "debit"
            self.amount = -self.amount.abs
        end
    end

    def update_account_balance_new
        @account = Account.find(account_id)
        @account.update_attributes(current_balance: @account.current_balance + amount)
    end

    def update_account_balance_edit
        @account = Account.find(account_id)
        if saved_change_to_amount?
            @account.update_attributes(current_balance: @account.current_balance - amount_was + amount)
        end
    end

    def update_account_balance_destroy
        @account = Account.find(account_id)
        @account.update_attributes(current_balance: @account.current_balance - amount_was)
    end

end
```

Basically my app allows users to create bank accounts, then add transactions to them to keep track of finances.  I wanted to add a running balance at the transaction level, so I created a view which joins back to the transactions table 1:1 ....

**Migration for view**

```
class CreateTransactionBalancesView < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
    def up
        execute <<-SQL
          CREATE VIEW transaction_balances AS (
            SELECT id AS transaction_id,
                   SUM(amount) OVER(PARTITION BY account_id ORDER BY trx_date, id) AS running_balance
              FROM transactions
          )
        SQL
    end

    def down
        execute("DROP VIEW transaction_balances")
    end
end
```

Now, when I created a model for this view, I had issues referencing "belongs_to :transaction" because it was complaining that "transaction" was a reserved word, so I had to find a workaround, as seen in my model below:

**transaction_balance.rb**

```
class TransactionBalance < ApplicationRecord
    self.primary_key = "transaction_id"

    #belongs_to :transaction
    belongs_to :user_transaction, foreign_key: "transaction_id", class_name: "Transaction"
end
```

**transactions_controller.rb**

```
class TransactionsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :find_account
    before_action :find_transaction, only: [:edit, :update, :show, :destroy]

    # Index action to render all transactions
    def index
        @transactions = @account.transactions.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 25)

        respond_to do |format|
            format.html # index.html.erb
            format.xml  { render :xml => @transactions }
        end
    end

    # New action for creating transaction
    def new
        @transaction = @account.transactions.build

        respond_to do |format|
          format.html # new.html.erb
          format.xml  { render :xml => @transaction }
        end
    end

    # Create action saves the trasaction into database
    def create
        @transaction = @account.transactions.build(transaction_params)

        respond_to do |format|
            if @transaction.save
                format.html { redirect_to([@transaction.account, @transaction], :notice => 'Transaction was successfully created.') }
                format.xml  { render :xml => @transaction, :status => :created, :location => [@transaction.account, @transaction] }
            else
                format.html { render :action => "new" }
                format.xml  { render :xml => @transaction.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
            end
        end
    end

    # Edit action retrieves the transaction and renders the edit page
    def edit
    end

      # Update action updates the transaction with the new information
    def update
        respond_to do |format|
            if @transaction.update_attributes(transaction_params)
                format.html { redirect_to([@transaction.account, @transaction], :notice => 'Transaction was successfully updated.') }
                format.xml  { head :ok }
            else
                format.html { render :action => "edit" }
                format.xml  { render :xml => @transaction.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
            end
        end
    end

    # The show action renders the individual transaction after retrieving the the id
    def show
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html # show.html.erb
            format.xml  { render :xml => @transaction }
        end
    end

    # The destroy action removes the transaction permanently from the database
    def destroy
        @transaction.destroy

        respond_to do |format|
            format.html { redirect_to(account_transactions_url) }
            format.xml  { head :ok }
        end
    end

    private

    def transaction_params
        params.require(:transaction).permit(:trx_date, :description, :amount, :trx_type, :memo)
    end

    def find_account
        @account = current_user.accounts.find(params[:account_id])
    end

    def find_transaction
        @transaction = @account.transactions.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

**And finally, my transactions index view, where I reference the running_balance field**

```
<% @transactions.with_balance.desc.each do |transaction| %>
                        <tr class="row m-0">
                            <td class="col-sm-1 text-center"><%= link_to transaction.id, [transaction.account, transaction] %></td>
                            <td class="col-sm-1 text-center"><%= transaction.trx_date.strftime('%m/%d/%Y') %></td>
                            <td class="col-sm-4"><%= transaction.description %></td>
                            <td class="col-sm-2 text-right"><%= if transaction.amount >= 0 then number_to_currency(transaction.amount) end %></td>
                            <td class="col-sm-2 text-right"><%= if transaction.amount < 0 then "(" + number_to_currency(transaction.amount.abs) + ")" end %></td>
                            <td class="col-sm-2 text-right"><%= number_to_currency(transaction.running_balance) %></td>

                        </tr>
                    <% end %>
```

Now, my problem is when I access the transactions index page in browser, my server console shows the following:

```
Started GET "/accounts/1/transactions" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-03-28 16:32:08 -0400
Processing by TransactionsController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"account_id"=>"1"}
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Account Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "accounts".* FROM "accounts" WHERE "accounts"."user_id" = $1 AND "accounts"."id" = $2 LIMIT $3  [["user_id", 1], ["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendering transactions/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Transaction Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "transactions".* FROM "transactions" INNER JOIN "transaction_balances" ON "transaction_balances"."transaction_id" = "transactions"."id" WHERE "transactions"."account_id" = $1 ORDER BY trx_date, id DESC LIMIT $2 OFFSET $3  [["account_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 25], ["OFFSET", 0]]
  TransactionBalance Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "transaction_balances".* FROM "transaction_balances" WHERE "transaction_balances"."transaction_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["transaction_id", 8], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  TransactionBalance Load (1.5ms)  SELECT  "transaction_balances".* FROM "transaction_balances" WHERE "transaction_balances"."transaction_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["transaction_id", 7], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  TransactionBalance Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "transaction_balances".* FROM "transaction_balances" WHERE "transaction_balances"."transaction_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["transaction_id", 6], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  TransactionBalance Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "transaction_balances".* FROM "transaction_balances" WHERE "transaction_balances"."transaction_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["transaction_id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  TransactionBalance Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "transaction_balances".* FROM "transaction_balances" WHERE "transaction_balances"."transaction_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["transaction_id", 4], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  TransactionBalance Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "transaction_balances".* FROM "transaction_balances" WHERE "transaction_balances"."transaction_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["transaction_id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  TransactionBalance Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "transaction_balances".* FROM "transaction_balances" WHERE "transaction_balances"."transaction_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["transaction_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (1.8ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "transactions" WHERE "transactions"."account_id" = $1  [["account_id", 1]]
  Rendered transactions/index.html.erb within layouts/application (59.8ms)
  Account Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "accounts".* FROM "accounts" WHERE "accounts"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 1]]
  Rendered layouts/_navbar.html.erb (3.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 255ms (Views: 169.1ms | ActiveRecord: 19.5ms)
```

As seen above, the view is being selected from for each individual record.  What I expect it to do is to join the transactions table with the transaction_balances view in one single select statement.  Any help on this would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `TransactionsController#index` action, change this line:

```
@transactions = @account.transactions.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 25)
```

to this (credit to @engineersmnky):

```
@transactions = @account.transactions.includes(:transaction_balance).references(:transaction_balance).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 25)
```

This will generate a single query that allows your view to access the transaction_balance for each transaction without going back to the database.

Comment: I changed my scope to includes instead of joins.  I now get transaction_balances in one query.  Is there any way to get transactions AND transaction_balances in one query?

Comment: @odinsride do you mean something like `@account.transactions.eager_load(:transaction_balance)` or `@account.transactions.includes(:transaction_balance).references(:transaction_balance)`? Both of these will execute as a single query for `Transaction`s and their `TransactionBalance`. Alternatively you could just take the 1 column you need from `transaction_balances` like `@account.transactions.joins(:transaction_balance).select("transactions.*,transaction_balances.running_balance as 'running_balance')` then `#running_balance` would be a virtual attribute of the `Transaction` object

Comment: @engineersmnky I stand corrected. I didn't want to go into the `select` technique with virtual attributes, but adding `references(:transaction_balance)` is simple and does indeed result in a single query.

Comment: Ah yes, I updated the scope for my model to be `scope :with_balance, -> { includes(:transaction_balance).references(:transaction_balance) }` and it works just as I want it to with only one query :)

Comment: Updated code to generate a single query per @engineersmnky.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you're not loading the `TransactionBalance` records when you load the transactions in your controller. Here's what you're doing:

```
@account.transactions
```

And here's what will fix the problem:

```
@account.transactions.with_balance
```

This will use the `with_balance` scope in your model, which does `joins(:balance)`, which will load both the transacations and all their balances in the one query.

Comment: I just updated my original post with the full contents of my transactions controller. Perhaps I'm doing something wrong there?

Comment: `joins` just creates an  `INNER JOIN` but it will not load them in the same query. maybe you meant `includes().references()` or `eager_load()`

Comment: `joins` loads the data from the `transactions` and `transaction_balances` table _in the same query_. If you go to query a transaction balance on a transaction loaded through a join, it _will not_ execute another query.

Comment: @RyanBigg not sure this is true since the query generated does not load any data for `transaction_balances` (e.g. `SELECT transactions.* FROM transactions INNER JOIN transaction_balances ON transaction_balances.transaction_id = transactions.transaction_id` does not have any `transaction_balances` data)  it would need to execute at least 1 additional query to load that data and in a loop would cause the `n+1`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where you're getting your `@account` from in your `TransactionsController`, but you may want to do a `join` or an `includes`.

For instance, `@account = Account.includes(:transactions).find(params[:account_id])` before you query the transactions will eager load the transactions and pull them in one query rather than "n+1-ing" them.

[The API dock entry](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes) can tell you more about the `includes` method

and

[This article](https://blog.codeship.com/speed-up-activerecord/) can tell you more about how to get rid of the n+1 querying problem.

Good luck!

Comment: Whoops, looks like I didn't see that all the queries were from TransactionBalance not Transaction. The principle remains the same though :]